# Using TTaskBar before creating the application's main form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

My application displays a "download form" with a progress bar while downloading updates and after finishing it destroys the "download form" and creates the application's main form.

[image: picture of a download form with a progressbar]

The "download form" is not set as the application's main form (its created as `MyDownloadForm := TMyDownloadForm.Create(nil)`) and is displayed in the Windows task bar thank to the `CreateParams` overrided as follows:

```
procedure TMyDownloadForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
end;
```

I'm trying to display the download progress on the Windows task bar using a [`TTaskBar`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Taskbar.TTaskbar) component, placed on the download form, but it seems to have no effect on the Windows task bar (no progress, no color, nothing...).

If I create the "download form" as application's main form (`Application.CreateForm(TMyDownloadForm, MyDownloadForm)`) it works good instead.

I honestly don't remember if there was a pratical reason for avoiding to temporarily set the "download form" as application's main form, probably it was seeming cleaner to have only one main form in the program's life-time.

Anyhow, I would like to know if there is any way to use the [`TTaskBar`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Taskbar.TTaskbar) component (or any other solution for displaying a progress on the task bar) with a "common form" (not application main form).

Comment: It might be better to use the Win32 interface directly.

Comment: I would have to check its source code to verify, but it sounds like `TTaskBar` is not designed to handle Taskbar buttons added "manually" via `CreateParams()`, but only Taskbar buttons controlled by `TApplication(.MainForm)`. That would be a serious limitation of the component if that is true. So, I agree with Andreas, you should just use the Win32 [`ITaskbarList3`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist3) interface directly.